# Remove Alphabetic characters from a string, leaving numbers and symbols

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a bunch of strings that I'm trying to parse the date out of.  I have a script that will parse the date, but it's having trouble with all the extra letters in the string.  I need to remove all the letters but leave characters such as - / _

I'm not particularly good with Regex, so all attempts to do this so far have ended with too many characters getting removed.

Here's a few sample strings to help:

> Littleton, CO - Go-Live 5/8
>
> Brunswick - Go-Live 5/14
>
> CutSheeet_Go Live-5-14-14
>
> Go Live - 5-19-2014

Comment: You don't even need regex!  Don't complicate it just because Regex can do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "([a-zA-Z,_ ]+|(?<=[a-zA-Z ])[/-])", "");
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/kD2jF4

From your example data, output would be:

```
5/8
5/14
5-14-14
5-19-2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
public static string Parse(string source)
{
    var numbers = new [] {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' };
    var chars = new [] { '-', '/', '_' };

    return  new string(source
            .Where(x => numbers.Contains(x) || chars.Contains(x))
            .ToArray()).Trim(chars); 
}
```

Here is [`fiddle`](http://dotnetfiddle.net/RUcuWR)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string StripCrap(string input)
{
    return input.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c) || c == '_' || c == '/' || 
                       c == '-').Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + c);
}
```

Or, if you want a maintainable list:

```
public static string StripCrap(string input)
{
    char[] nonCrapChars = {'/', '-', '_'};

    return input.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c) || nonCrapChars.Contains(c)).Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + c);
}
```

Or...You could also create an extension method:

```
public static string ToNonCrappyString(this string input)
{
    char[] nonCrapChars = {'/', '-', '_'};

    return input.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c) || nonCrapChars.Contains(c)).Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + c);
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
string myString = "Hello 1234!";
string nonCrappyString = myString.ToNonCrappyString();
```

Comment: Why not `.Where(c => !char.IsLetter(c))`?

Comment: That `Aggregate` takes quadratic time.  `ToArray` and a `String` constructor call would be linear.

Comment: @ErikPhilips -- Because he said he didn't want `/`, `-`, or `_` to be filtered

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `.*?(\d+[\d-\/]*\d+)|.*` and replace with `$1` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pY0mK0)